# How do I pass parameters from a component into an event listener in React?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, react-props

In my App.jsx I have an event handler and a returned component:

```
handleSell = (price) => (event) => {
        console.log(price);

}
render() {
    return(
    <SellCatalogLine 
        key = {item.ORDERID} 
        price = {item.PRICE} 
        title = {item.TITLE} 
        handleSell = {this.handleSell}/>
    )}
```

My component looks like this:

```
function SellCatalogLine(props){

    const currentprice = props.price
    const cheaperprice = currentprice - 100;

    return (
        <div>
        <h3>{props.title}</h3>
        <p>Lowest Price: ${currentprice}</p>
        <button type="submit" onClick = {() => props.handleSell(currentprice)}>List item at ${currentprice} </button>
        <button type="submit" onClick = {() => props.handleSell(cheaperprice)}>List item at ${cheaperprice} </button> 
        </div>
    )
};
```

I'm trying to make it so that the console will log cheaperprice or currentprice depending on which button I click. How do I do that?

Comment: seems like you are doing it correctly in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `handleSell` method when called returns another function so you need to call `props.handleSell(currentprice)` in `SellCatalogLine` component.

i.e.

```
handleSell = (price) => (event) => {
   console.log(price);
}
```

And use it as

```
<button type="submit" onClick = {props.handleSell(currentprice)}>List item at ${currentprice} </button>
```

If `handleSell` method did not return a function then you could use an anonymous function. In which you could call `props.handleSell(currentprice)`

i.e

```
handleSell = (event, price) => {
    console.log(price);
}
```

And use it as

```
<button type="submit" onClick = {(e) => props.handleSell(e, currentprice)}>List item at ${currentprice} </button>
```

Comment: What would I do if I wanted to pass in a parameter from the component, and another parameter from the App.jsx render?

Comment: You could use any approach from above to get data as argument to `handleSell` method from the component. And to get data from App.jsx you could keep the data in state and use it  in the method.